# How to hide element in php if condition satisfied?(without css,js)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, css

I have this condition and want to hide the element which is generated dynamically from js file.

```
if(!$config):?>
    <style type="text/css">.priority-nav .priority-nav__wrapper{display:none;}</style>
<?php endif;?>
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please post the code, where the element is generated.

Comment: If you're generating the element via JS wouldn't it make more sense to also control the visibility with JS? This sounds like a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed to Ben Crooks comment ... I don't know your JS code, but it could be solved in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var myConfigValue: <?php echo (int) Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('path/to/config') ?>

    if (myConfigValue) {
        // the code that generates this element
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

If you want to do this via PHP your code should work.